# Adding a top-margin to smoothscroll

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the following script to enable smoothscrolling on a one-page site.
For navigation I use a fixed navigation bar that sits on top of the page on a uppermost z-index layer. The hight of the bar is 108px, so when I use the smoothscroller, part of the section I want to navigate to gets hidden by the nav-bar.
My poor JS skills leaves me no other option than to consult some of you guys... how would I add a 108px top-margin to this script? anyone?

```
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     //go to destination
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dest` is your var to scroll

so all you have to do is take some values off from it before

`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');`

or within the execution of this line.

dest - 108

Comment: Thank you, quick and easy to understand answer